# Concatenate user input Strings to convert into a complete file path (Java)

Tags: java, file, io, concatenation

I wrote a short script to create a file to my Desktop, and the file appeared. I just did it all in main, like so:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class FilePractice {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //create a new File object
    File myFile = new File("/home/christopher/Desktop/myFile");

    try{
        System.out.println("Would you like to create a new file? Y or N: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String choice = input.nextLine();
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            myFile.createNewFile();
        }
        else
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while creating file " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("'myFile' " + myFile.getPath() + " created.");
  }
}
```

I just wanted to make sure the code worked, which it did. After that, I wanted to expand by creating a file with user input, as well as define which directory the user wished to send the file to. I'm on a Linux machine, and I wanted to send it to my Desktop again, so my user input was "/home/christopher/Desktop" for the userPath. Nothing happened. I even cd'd to my Desktop via terminal to "ls" everything there, and still nothing.

Perhaps my syntax is wrong?

If this is a duplicate of anything, my apologies. I tried to do a thorough search before coming here, but I only found info on creating files and sending files to directories that are already defined as a string (e.g. File myFile = new File("/home/User/Desktop/myFileName")).

Here is the expanded attempt:

```
try {
       System.out.println("Alright. You chose to create a new file.\nWhat would you like to name the file?");
            String fileName = input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter the directory where you would like to save this file.\nFor example: C:\\Users\\YourUserName\\Documents\\");
            String userFilePath = input.nextLine();
            File userFile = new File(userFilePath, fileName);
            System.out.println("Is this the file path you wish to save to? ----> " + userFile.getPath()+"\nY or N: ");
            String userChoice = input.nextLine();

            if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                userFile.createNewFile();
                //print for debug 
                System.out.println(userFile.getPath());
               }
            }catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error while attempting to create file " + e);
            }
            System.out.println("File created successfully");
```

My print statement for a debug attempt outputs "/home/christopher/Desktop", but not the file name appended to the directory.

Thanks for any help offered. This is just for experimentation while learning Java I/O. Since a hypothetical user may not be on the same OS as me, I can work on those methods later. I'm keeping it on my home machine, hence the Unix filepath names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing input.nextLine() to input.next() solved the problem. The program was not reaching the if statement after asking the user if they were sure their entered path was the desired save point.

I also put in a simple else statement that printed out ("File not created") to verify that it was skipping it.

Anyway, question answered. :-)